# Spring set abstract bean property value

Tags: java, spring

I need to chance spring bean property values on runtime. Currently I'm doing it this way

```
Object bean = context.getBean(beanName);
BeanWrapper wrapper = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(bean);
wrapper.setPropertyValue(propertyName, newValue);
```

But some beans are configured as abstract

```
<bean id="abstractFoo" abstract="true" class="com.Foo" />

<bean id="bar" class="com.Bar">
    <constructor-arg><bean parent="abstractFoo" /></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

and in that case `context.getBean("abstractFoo")` throws `BeanIsAbstractException`

This is really simplified example, but I hope you get the idea.

Any idea how to change property value of abstract bean (in this case 'abstractFoo')?
We're using spring 2.5.4

**Edit**

Changed a XML example to be more specific. abstractFoo is declared abstract because of security reasons.

Comment: You need to bare careful to distinguish a bean from a bean definition. For example `<bean id="foo" parent="abstractFoo" />` does *not* represent a bean, just a bean definition. So you can't ask for a bean by that name, but there is no such bean.

Answer (score 2):

Spring application context contains *bean definitions*, and Spring instantiates bean objects defined by these definitions.

Your current code obtains an object that was created from the named bean definition, and changes its property. However, `abstract` beans are never instantiated as objects, they exist only in the form of definitions which are inherited by definitions of concrete beans.

So, if you want to change properties of abstract beans, you need to change their definitions, that can be done using [`BeanFactoryPostProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factory-postprocessors). Note, however, that post-processors are applied during container startup, so if you want it to be actually "runtime", you this approach is not applicable.

Comment: Yes, it has to be done "runtime" Whole idea of this thing is that support could change configuration parameters without restarting application afterwards.

Comment: @vrm: I think that changing configuration at runtime is more complex than simple modification of bean properties. In general, your objects should be designed to allow runtime configuration changes. For example, you can introduce a separate configuration holder object, and make your objects retrieve configuration properties from it.

Comment: Sure, but unfortunately it's too late for that

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this is untested; off the top of my head.  Not sure if it will work after the init phase.

You need to get in instance of a `ConfigurableListableBeanFactory`.  Your appcontext probably is one, so you can probably cast it.

From there, get the bean definition and change the property.

```
   ConfigurableListableBeanFactory clbf = (ConfigurableListableBeanFactory)context;
   BeanDefinition fooDefinition = clbf.getBeanDefinition("abstractFoo");
   MutablePropertyValues pv = fooDefinition.getPropertyValues();
   pv.add(propertyName, newValue);
```

Maybe you need to re-register your beandefinition with the `ConfigurableListableBeanFactory` after that.  I'm not 100% sure; you'll have to test that.

Keep in mind that if it works, it will only work for beans that are instantiated **after** the change.